Using Assumed Rank with Unlimited Polymorphic Issues
There must be something I'm misunderstanding.
I'm attempting to use an assumed rank unlimited polymorphic variable to store data. When I do this I either get access violations or corrupted data. I built a little toy problem to showcase the issue (listed below). The first is an access violation and the second is the corrupted data.
Access Violation
   real, target :: x
   class(*), pointer :: x_ptr

   x = 5.6
   x_ptr => x
   call do_stuff(x_ptr)

contains

   subroutine do_stuff(item)

       class(*), dimension(..), intent(in) :: item

       select rank(item)
       rank(0)
           select type(item) !<--- this is where the debugger crashes
           type is (real)
               print *, item
           end select
       end select

   end subroutine do_stuff

Corrupted Data
   real, target :: x
   class(*), pointer :: x_ptr

   x = 5.6
   x_ptr => x
   call do_stuff(x_ptr)

contains

   subroutine do_stuff(item)

       class(*), dimension(..), intent(in) :: item

       select rank(item)
       rank(0)
           call do_stuff_inner(item)
       end select

   end subroutine do_stuff

   subroutine do_stuff_inner(item)

       class(*), intent(in) :: item

       select type(item)
       type is (real)
           print *, item ! prints 4.735692598010119E-312
       end select

   end subroutine do_stuff_inner

I appreciate any explanation of what I'm doing wrong. I'm using intel fortran oneapi 2023.0.0.25839. Also to test for posting it does work on this compiler https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_fortran_compiler

Both work for me with ifx (IFX) 2024.2.0 20240602 using no compiler flags  - ijb@ijb-SER:~/play/stack/fortran$ ifx unp1.f90; ./a.out    5.600000   . Could you edit the question to show the exact compilation line you are using in each case just to check that it isn't a compiler flag that is causing the issue.

From the intel forums as well. It seems like the best solution is just to update to newest.
